# How can i login in network devices with paramiko by ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to login in network devices by ssh.I have got the correct output after I executed the first command, but strange error occurs when I execute the second command.

```
import paramiko

paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.INFO)
paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_router_simple.log')
try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    hostname='192.168.1.1'
    username='test'
    password='test'
    client.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password,look_for_keys = False,allow_agent = False)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('show ip inter b')
    print stdout.read()
    # error occurs after I execute the second command
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('show ip inter b')
    print stdout.read()
finally:
    client.close()
```

the strange error shows below

```
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.841] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20151125-09:26:42.852] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.876] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.883] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 4096 bytes
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.883] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.901] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.925] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.925] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.927] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.928] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Ignoring message for dead channel 0
DEB [20151125-09:26:42.928] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

I also open the debug on router and capture the debug info

```
*Mar  1 00:17:09.639: SSH2 0: done calc MAC out #11
*Mar  1 00:17:09.639: SSH0: Session terminated normally
 R1#
```

Accoring to the explanation of this method called exec_command,this method will execute a command on the server.  If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly connected to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the command being executed.When the command finishes executing, the channel will be closed and can't be reused.  You must open a new channel if you wish to execute another command.

What make me confused is that why exec_command close this ssh connection rather than the channel? Is there anyone else who run as the same problem like me ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not try fabric. Much easier for such work

Comment: The log is for the second `exec_command` call only? Or for both? If both, what part is for which call?

Comment: The paramiko log is for both, `[chan 0]` means the first exec_command and `[chan 1]` is the second.But the second command execute failure.
the router log show the process of  the first command ,but the session terminated normailly after execute the  command.